# is there a way to align in height two tables placed next to each other?

Tags: html, css, html-table

If I have a situation like this:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="100%">
        <table width="640">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="100%" id="column1">
                <table id="right">
                  ......
                </table>
              </td>
              <td width="100%" id="column2">
                <table id="left">
                  ......
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible to make **column1** and **column2** the ***same height without giving a fixed height***?

I can't use javascript, and flexbox only css/html is a code not created by me, for email design.

Comment: Please provide a complete example showing the problem. I see nothing in the demo above except some dots. Some table styles would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just apply them same class for `height` but still keep different id for other properties, so they will always have same height as long as they have the same class:

(Here these are div but same processus with table)

```css
#container{
display: flex;
}

.height{
height: 100px;   //and if you want height not fixed just set it auto or fit-content...
}

#width1{
width: 70%;
background-color: red;
}

#width2{
width: 30%;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="width1" class="height">
  div 1
  </div>
  <div id="width2" class="height">
  div 2
  </div>
</div>
```